# How to gracefully terminate a multithreaded Python application that uses queue.Queue

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue, terminate

I have been trying to get my application to terminate gracefully for quite some time now, but so far none of the answers I have found worked.

The sample code below illustrates the structure of my application. It basically is a chain of threads that passes data to one another using Queues.

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue
import signal
import sys


class StoppableThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stopper = Event()
        self.queue = Queue()

    @abstractmethod
    def actual_job(self):
        pass

    def stop_running(self):
        self.stopper.set()


    def run(self):
        while not self.stopper.is_set():
            print(self.stopper.is_set())
            self.actual_job()
        self.queue.join()

class SomeObjectOne(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, name, some_object_two):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.obj_two = some_object_two

    def actual_job(self):
        # print('{} is currently running'.format(self.name))
        input_string = 'some string'
        print('{} outputs {}'.format(self.name, input_string))
        self.obj_two.queue.put(input_string)
        sleep(2)

class SomeObjectTwo(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, name, some_object_three):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.some_object_three = some_object_three


    def actual_job(self):
        # print('{} is currently running'.format(self.name))
        some_string = self.queue.get()
        inverted = some_string[::-1]
        print('{} outputs {}'.format(self.name , inverted))
        self.some_object_three.queue.put(inverted)
        sleep(2)


class SomeObjectThree(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def actual_job(self):
        print('{} is currently running'.format(self.name))
        some_string = self.queue.get()
        print('{} outputs {}'.format(self.name ,some_string[::-1]))
        sleep(2)




class ServiceExit(Exception):
    """
    Custom exception which is used to trigger the clean exit
    of all running threads and the main program.
    """
    pass

def service_shutdown(signum, frame):
    print('Caught signal %d' % signum)
    raise ServiceExit

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, service_shutdown)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, service_shutdown)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_three = SomeObjectThree('SomeObjectThree')
    thread_two = SomeObjectTwo('SomeObjectTwo', thread_three)
    thread_one = SomeObjectOne('SomeObjectOne', thread_two)

    try:
        thread_three.start()
        thread_two.start()
        thread_one.start()

        # Keep the main thread running, otherwise signals are ignored.
        while True:
            sleep(0.5)

    except ServiceExit:
        print('Running service exit')
        thread_three.stop_running()
        thread_two.stop_running()
        thread_one.stop_running()
        thread_one.join()
        thread_two.join()
        thread_three.join()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Now, if I run this code and ctrl-C to terminate, `thread_one` seems to join as expected, but the code gets stuck at `thread_two.join()`.

Because `thread_one` is the only thread with a continuous empty queue, I expect it has something to do with the queue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `run()` method of `StoppableThread` you have this:

```
self.queue.join()
```

`join()` [is a blocking method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html):

> Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
>   queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls
>   task_done() to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it
>   is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join()
>   unblocks.

So in order for `join()` to return, it's not enough to `get()` an item in the other thread, you must also indicate that it's been processed with `task_done()`:

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue
import signal
import sys

class StoppableThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stopper = Event()
        self.queue = Queue()

    @abstractmethod
    def actual_job(self):
        pass

    def stop_running(self):
        self.stopper.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopper.is_set():
            print(self.stopper.is_set())
            self.actual_job()
        self.queue.join()

class SomeObjectOne(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, name, some_object_two):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.obj_two = some_object_two

    def actual_job(self):
        # print('{} is currently running'.format(self.name))
        input_string = 'some string'
        print('{} outputs {}'.format(self.name, input_string))
        self.obj_two.queue.put(input_string)
        sleep(2)

class SomeObjectTwo(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, name, some_object_three):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.some_object_three = some_object_three

    def actual_job(self):
        # print('{} is currently running'.format(self.name))
        some_string = self.queue.get()
        inverted = some_string[::-1]
        print('{} outputs {}'.format(self.name , inverted))
        self.queue.task_done()
        self.some_object_three.queue.put(inverted)
        sleep(2)

class SomeObjectThree(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def actual_job(self):
        print('{} is currently running'.format(self.name))
        some_string = self.queue.get()
        print('{} outputs {}'.format(self.name ,some_string[::-1]))
        self.queue.task_done()
        sleep(2)

class ServiceExit(Exception):
    """
    Custom exception which is used to trigger the clean exit
    of all running threads and the main program.
    """
    pass

def service_shutdown(signum, frame):
    print('Caught signal %d' % signum)
    raise ServiceExit

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, service_shutdown)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, service_shutdown)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_three = SomeObjectThree('SomeObjectThree')
    thread_two = SomeObjectTwo('SomeObjectTwo', thread_three)
    thread_one = SomeObjectOne('SomeObjectOne', thread_two)

    try:
        thread_three.start()
        thread_two.start()
        thread_one.start()

        # Keep the main thread running, otherwise signals are ignored.
        while True:
            sleep(0.5)

    except ServiceExit:
        print('Running service exit')
        thread_three.stop_running()
        thread_two.stop_running()
        thread_one.stop_running()
        thread_one.join()
        thread_two.join()
        thread_three.join()
```